# Manually managed transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I have a code where transaction control is done manually,
But the code calls methods of other EJB's of the same application where the transaction is not controlled manually, for example, there are methods using the Hibernate Session that is managed by the Container.

How to prevent my manually managed transaction from downloading the commit when there is a query method using eg a Session.createCriteria.

When this occurs, my transaction unloads the commit before my process is actually completed.

**Example**

```
private void exe() throws Exception {
   @EJB Businessbusiness;
       this.beginTransaction();
            business.processar(); // Exemplo
        this.commit();
    }


@Stateless
public class Business() {
    @EJB 
    private DAO dao;

    private void processar() throws Exception {
     // executando processo 1
      this.save();

      // executando processo 2
      this.update();

      // Saving and updating has not yet been committed. So far it is correct.

     Teste = dao.buscarTeste(1L);

     // Here, after performing the search, my transaction downloads the commit to the bank without completing the whole process.
    }
}

@Stateless
public class DAO() {
     public Teste buscarTeste(Long codigo) {

        Criteria cri = getSession().createCriteria(Teste.class);

        cri.add(Restrictions.eq("codigo", codigo)); 

        return (Teste) cri.uniqueResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I actually got your point.

But assuming you are not getting any error, when you invoke the `Business.processar()` method it inherits the transaction. Which remains 'pending' until the exe client commit.

So, I would investigate what your `getSession()` does in the middle, I am quite sure it starts a brand new transaction, which is going to retrieve uncommitted data.

By the way, is there a reason for using hibernate instead of JPA with hibernate as a concrete implementation ?

Comment: It is the default of a framework of the company itself, the getSession is encapsulated in it where I can not access. Thank you for your response, Leonardo, I really do not understand this behavior either.

Comment: Uhm...in this case, I think that the only acceptable reason is that the DAO is starting a brand new transaction.

Comment: Thank you Leonardo